# How to pass values from html page to .aspx page?

Tags: c#

i have

```
<input type ="text" id ="ID" value="" />
<input type ="text" id="Name" value ="" />
<input type="button" id="Submit" name="Submit"  value="Submit" size ="45" />
```

when i click Submit button to pass values to .aspx page.

Answer (score 4):

If you post a form to an aspx page you can get the submitted values through the `Request.Form` collection.  From your example:

You'll need to set the action on your form to the aspx page:

```
<form action="mypage.aspx">
```

And set the name on your field:

```
<input type ="text" name="ID" id="ID" value="" />
```

You can get them on the aspx with:

```
string id = Request.Form["ID"];
```

Comment: I have to separate Html and aspx pages

Comment: That's fine - this will still work.  Any POST elements will be mapped to the `Form` collection.

Comment: I tried with above scenario return null values in mypage.aspx page

Comment: Make sure the form is multipart:  enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

```
<input type ="text" id ="ID" value="" runat="server"/>
```

Have a look at [ASP.NET - Server Controls](http://www.w3schools.com/ASPNET/aspnet_controls.asp)

Comment: HTML and aspx pages are different.